# How to remove double quotes inside quotes in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like

```
string = 'Test 180 "go = "Sit""'
```

I would like to remove the double quote inside the doubles and return something like this

```
'Test 180 "go = Sit"'
```

Comment: What do you want the outcome to be???

Comment: How do you know `"go = "Sit""` is nested quotes and not `"go = "`, `Sit`, `""`?

Comment: I'm just looking for a sanity check. There's no way to do this programatically without being able to assume "Okay there's for sure only one quoted section in the string" or etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following rather dirty approach:

```
string = 'Test 180 "go = "Sit""'
print '\0'.join(string.replace('"', '\0', 1).rsplit('"', 1)).replace('"', '').replace('\0', '"')
```

This would give the following output:

```
Test 180 "go = Sit"
```

To explain how this works:

1. Firstly it replaces the first double quote with an unused character (namely `\0`).
2. It then replaces the last double quote with the same unused character. As there is no `rreplace()` function in Python, this is achieved using `rsplit`.
3. Any remaining double quotes are removed.
4. Finally, the two `\0`s are replaced with double quotes.